# SQL selecting from multiple tables and ordering by certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `customer` and `tickets`

I want to be able to select from the tickets table and order by:

`tickets.priority` then `customer.category_priority` then `tickets.queue_time`

I have this query:

```
SELECT t.*
from tickets t
  JOIN customer c ON t.company = c.sequence
WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' AND t.queue = 'Y'
ORDER BY field(t.priority, 'Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low'), t.queue_time ASC
```

which works great for the `tickets.priority` and `tickets.queue_time`

but im not sure how to incorporate the `customer.category_priority`

so in the customer table, i have columns with names like:

```
priority_computers
priority_telephone
priority_software
```

all INT fields and have a value of 0, 1 or 2

the row in `tickets` has a `category` column which is either `Computers`, `Telephone`, or `Software` and thats what needs to link to the above.

so, if a customer row has `priority_computers` of 2 and the `tickets` row is `category = 'Computers'` that would be at the top of the list because the customer record has the priority of `2` and it would also incorporate the other `ORDER BY` conditions

Examples:

Customers:

- Company A      priority_computers = 1
- Company B         priority_computers = 2
- Company C      priority_computers = 3

Example One:

- Ticket 1     Company A     priority = Medium     category = Computers
  queue_time = 2015-11-20 08:00
- Ticket 2     Company B     priority = Medium     category = Computers
  queue_time = 2015-11-20 10:00:00
- Ticket 3     Company C     priority = Medium     category = Computers
  queue_time = 2015-11-20 08:30:00

This should output in the following order:

- Ticket 3
- Ticket 2
- Ticket 1

Example 2:

- Ticket 1     Company B     priority = High     category = Computers
  queue_time = 2015-11-20 12:00
- Ticket 2     Company A     priority = Medium     category = Computers
  queue_time = 2015-11-20 07:00:00
- Ticket 3     Company C     priority = Medium     category = Computers
  queue_time = 2015-11-20 07:00:00

This should output in the following order:

- Ticket 1
- Ticket 3
- Ticket 2

Comment: Can you give sample data and expected output?

Comment: check my update, ive given some examples of dummy data which i hope will help

Comment: So there is exactly one customer per ticket? (`JOIN customer c ON t.company = c.sequence` is a bit confusing then, I'd have expected it to be `JOIN customer c ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id`). Or can there be more customers for one ticket? If so, how to deal with that?

Comment: there is one customer per ticket however each customer could have more than 1 ticket

Comment: if there is a better way to store this information in the database then im open to ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, then your problem is that you have to match data with column names somehow.

- customer.priority_computers for ticket.category = 'Computers'
- customer.priority_telephone for ticket.category = 'Telephone'
- customer.priority_software for ticket.category = 'Software'

This shows a database design flaw. There should be a customer_priority table instead with each row holding a customer, a category and the associated value. Then you could simply join.

As is, you must check data content and decide for a column to use in your query:

```
SELECT t.*
from tickets t
  JOIN customer c ON t.company = c.sequence
WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' AND t.queue = 'Y'
ORDER BY field(t.priority, 'Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low')
  , case t.category 
      when 'Computers' then c.priority_computers
      when 'Telephone' then c.priority_telephone
      when 'Software' then c.priority_software
    end
  , t.queue_time ASC
```

Update: Here is a query you'd write, if you had a customer_priority table. You see, your query doesn't need to know what categories exist and how to treat them any longer.

```
SELECT t.*
from tickets t
  JOIN customer c ON t.company = c.sequence
  JOIN customer_priority cp ON cp.customer_id = c.sequence
                            AND cp.category = t.category
WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' AND t.queue = 'Y'
ORDER BY field(t.priority, 'Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low')
  , cp.priority_value
  , t.queue_time ASC
```

Moreover: As mentioned, it is strange to have a table `customer`, but in `tickets` it's not called a *customer*, but a *company*, and in the `customer` table itself it's not called a *customer* number or ID either, but a *sequence*. This makes the queries less readable. I suggest, you change the names, if possible, so they are consistent.

Also your query shouldn't have to know what 'Critical' and 'High' means. There should be a table for priorities where each priority has a name and a value, so the query could simply pick the value and work with it without having to know anything else about the priorities.

Comment: i can create a table with this information, that wouldn't be a problem. if i do, what would then be the query needed

Comment: excellent - what happens if no rows exist in the customer_priority table - this may sometimes be the case

Comment: You could simply insert records with a default value then. Or you change `JOIN customer_priority` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_priority`. In that case you might also want to change `cp.priority_value` to something like `coalesce(cp.priority_value, 99999)` to have these come last.